# Why can I not use my BSNL USB Modem(LW273) ?

Tags: 12.10, usb, usb-modem, modem

I have BSNL USB Modem LW273 7.2MBPs data card. I had used it on windows 7. Now I use Ubuntu 12.10. But I am unable to use this USB modem on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please don't post an URL to some unrelated page.

Answer (score 0):

You should try wvdial, it should be available in the synaptics, it makes the setup process for datacards much easier. You can also install it by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

Also, do explore the network applet and check the settings before you are confirmed. I think you didn't do the latter thoroughly.